# Get Network Operator of Called number In Android

Tags: android, gsm

Is it possible to get the network operator name and details of incoming and outgoing call numbers in android?
For example If incoming/outgoing call number is from `+1650670XXXX`, is it possible to get the network operator as `AT&T`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i get the carrier name of an incoming number in android..?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669653/how-do-i-get-the-carrier-name-of-an-incoming-number-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Find in these links it will be usefull for you

http://androidexample.com/How_to_get_Network_Operator_Name_and_Device_Name/question_answer.php?view=qad&token=21

http://sampleprogramz.com/android/networktype.php

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the operator name from a dialled or incoming number in most countries because of Number Portability.

In simple terms this means that a number which was originally assigned by one operator (say ATT&T) may now be owned by another operator (say Verizon), and there is no way to tell from the number itself as it remains unchanged:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_number_portability

The operators have mechanisms to allow them determine who actually currently 'provides' a given number, as they need this information to allow them route calls to numbers which have been ported, but I am not aware of any examples where access to these mechanisms is freely available to anyone outside of the operators themselves. There are some companies advertising a look up service for numbers which might meet your needs, but they tend to charge for this - e.g.:

http://www.numberportabilitylookup.com/hlr_lookup