# How can i get the Service provider name of other phone numbers in contacts list of an Android device programmatically?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an app which can manage all incoming and outgoing call. However the fee of service providers is different. Therefore i'm finding a way to check 2 phone numbers are in the same provider or not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get the name of the Current Network Operator to which the Android phone is currently connected is to get hold of the `android.telephony.TelephonyManager` and get it from there:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager =((TelephonyManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
String operatorName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

similarly the sim operator can be retrieved by using:

```
String operatorName = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
```

if your looking for incoming number network operator name means follow this link.

[Incoming number carrier name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12669858/2169192)